# Check if inverse relationship exists in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a table for signifying friends/friend requests. Basically my idea was to have a table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE friends( 
    user_id NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
    friend_user_id NUMERIC NOT NULL 
    UNIQUE (user_id,friend_user_id)
)
```

When a user wants to create a friend requests you add a row:

```
INSERT INTO friends(user_id,friend_user_id) VALUES($1,$2)
```

Then when the other user accepts the friend request you would simply add the inverse of the previous row (i.e. the recipient would technically be sending a friend request back to the sender thus completing the friend relationship):

```
INSERT INTO friends(user_id,friend_user_id) VALUES($2,$1)
```

My question:

If I want to get all the friends of a user I would have to get all the rows with that user's id and I want to inner join that with another table that contains the user's information, how would I check within the query for whether the rows inverse relationship exists?

P.S. I think I could do it pretty easily doing multiple queries but I would rather only have one query if possible.

Comment: Hi There, welcome to SO. Great that you were able to figure it out. Please either add it as an answer and mark it as accepted or delete this question since you solved your problem. I recommend the first option. Cheers.

Comment: It won't let me mark it as accepted for 2 days

Comment: Not a problem. Come back after that time and mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
SELECT users.id,users.username,users.avatar FROM users 
   INNER JOIN friends ON users.id = friends.user_id
   WHERE friends.user_id = $1 AND 
   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM friends WHERE friend_user_id = $1 AND user_id = friends.user_id)
```